# CakePHP 3 - Easiest way to retrieve a single field from the database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2 I could do something like this:

```
$name = $this->User->field('name', ['email' => 'user@example.com']);
```

In CakePHP 3 you have to do something like this to achieve the same thing:

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');

$query = $users->find()
    ->select('name')
    ->where(['email' => 'user@example.com']);

$name = $query->isEmpty() ? null : $query->first()->name;
```

Is there a simpler way to perform these kinds of operations? I'm not very familiar with the new ORM.

---

**Edit:** I have added an example of a class which adds this behavior for Cake 3:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42136955/851885

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to add this functionality to any Table via a custom behavior.

Save as **src/Model/Behavior/EnhancedFinderBehavior.php**

---

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Behavior;

use Cake\ORM\Behavior;

/**
 * EnhancedFinder behavior
 * 
 * Behavior providing additional methods for retrieving data.
 */
class EnhancedFinderBehavior extends Behavior
{

    /**
     * Retrieve a single field value
     * 
     * @param  string $fieldName The name of the table field to retrieve.
     * @param  array $conditions An array of conditions for the find.
     * @return mixed The value of the specified field from the first row of the result set.
     */
    public function field($fieldName, array $conditions)
    {
        $field = $this->_table->getAlias() . '.' . $fieldName;
        $query = $this->_table->find()->select($field)->where($conditions);

        if ($query->isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return $query->first()->{$fieldName};
    }
}
```

***Note**: for CakePHP versions prior to 3.4, change the code to `$this->_table->alias()`, which was deprecated in favour of `getAlias()` in later versions.*

---

**Usage**

Add the behavior to your class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('EnhancedFinder');
    }
}
```

Now you can use the finder like Cake 2:

```
$name = $this->User->field('name', ['id' => 1]);
```

Comment: Now the `alias` method is deprecated. What's the closest way to update your code?

Comment: @Mark The newer method is `getAlias()`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This might be simpler than yours

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$name = $users->get(1)->name;
```

Make sure that when you use the get function, the parameter should be a primary key in the table.

Comment: Doesn't the query object for this method select all fields though, which means to get one field it may select 100 fields from the table?

Comment: @BadHorsie Yes. it gets all the fields. if you want to select one field for better performance, then you should use find method to select the field.

Comment: @Eric Lee, Thanks. You Save My Time.

Comment: Using this method for retrieving one field makes no sense. `$users->get(1)` will have done all the "hard work" already and you are asking to pass you one field value out of 100 fields it already possesses.

Comment: This method is also only for retrieving a record by ID, you can’t select any single field with it.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not in CakePHP 3.x.

If you want that method back implement it either in a behavior or as a finder using a trait and use it with your table objects.